# Find unmatched unique pairs of an array from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, recursion

I have a list of users and I have also list of pairs of matched users. i-e

```
const users = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"];
const alreadyMatchedUsers = [
    { user1: 'A', user2: 'B' },
    { user1: 'A', user2: 'C' },
  ]
```

I want to find list of unique unmatched users. By unique, I mean user pair AB and BA will be considered as 1 pair.

Here is the solution I have came up with:

```
const alreadyMatchedUsers = [
    { user1: 'A', user2: 'B' },
    { user1: 'A', user2: 'C' },
  ]

  const unMatchedArrary = []

  // const users = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

  const users = []

  for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) users.push(i)

  const n = users.length
  const uniquePossiblePairs = []
  const uniquePossiblePairsCount = (n * (n - 1)) / 2

  for (let i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    console.log('Main loop+++++++++++++++++', users[i])
    for (let j = i; j < n - 1; j++) {
      // uniquePossiblePairs.push({ user1: users[i], user2: users[j + 1] });
      const alreadyMatched = alreadyMatchedUsers.some(
        (mpair) => (users[i] === mpair.user1 || users[i] === mpair.user2)
          && (users[j + 1] === mpair.user1 || users[j + 1] === mpair.user2),
      )

      if (!alreadyMatched) {
        unMatchedArrary.push({ user1: users[i], user2: users[j + 1] })
      }

      console.log('Already Matched, ', users[i], users[j + 1], alreadyMatched)
    }
  }

  console.log('UNIQUE POSSIBLE PAIRS Count', uniquePossiblePairsCount)
  console.log('UNIQUE POSSIBLE PAIRS', uniquePossiblePairs)
  console.log('UNMATCHED ARRARY ', unMatchedArrary)
}
```

This solutions gives the expected results, But its very expensive operation. Try running this code with 300 users and if alreadyMatched users gets bigger, it will become way more expensive.

How can I get this to be faster?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
const users = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

const combinations = [];
while (users.length > 0) {
    const lastUser = users[users.length-1]; // start at last user of users list.
    
     // this loop gets all combinations involving the last user.
    for (let user of users) {
        if (user !== lastUser) {
            combinations.push({"user1": user, "user2": lastUser});
        }
    }
    
    // this gets rid of last user from the users list, as we have found all its combinations from this iteration of the while loop.
    users.pop()
}

console.log(combinations);
```

This algorithm ensures number of iterations == [number of possible combinations](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php).

Comment: they already do that: the inner loop `j` starts with `i`(should be `i+1` actually). However, "N choose 2" is still a huge number for large N.

Comment: Right. going to leave it as it might help with cleaning code a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve that:

```js
const users = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"];
const alreadyMatchedUsers = [
  { user1: 'A', user2: 'B' },
  { user1: 'A', user2: 'C' },
]
  
const pairs = alreadyMatchedUsers.map(x => `${x.user1}${x.user2},${x.user2}${x.user1}`);

let allPairs = [];

for (user of users) {
  allPairs.push(...users.map(x => `${user}${x},${x}${user}`))
}

// filter allPairs
const uniquePairs = allPairs
   .filter(pair => !pairs.includes(pair) && pair.split(',')[0] != pair.split(',')[1])
   .map(pair => pair.split(',')[0].split('')); 

console.log('pairs: ', pairs);
console.log('allPairs: ', allPairs);
console.log('uniquePairs', uniquePairs);
```

Comment: How about `AF`, `AG` etc?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this problem. I have replaced the matchedPairs from objects to arrays to simplify this.

```js
 const users = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"];
const alreadyMatchedUsers = [
  ["A", "B"],
  ["A", "C"],
];
const unmatchedPairs = [...alreadyMatchedUsers];
const unmatchedPairsFinal = [];
for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  users.forEach((user) => {
    if (user !== users[i]) {
      console.log("checking", user, " vs ", users[i]);
      const alreadyDetected = unmatchedPairs.filter((userCheck) => {
        return userCheck.includes(user) && userCheck.includes(users[i]);
      });
      console.log(alreadyDetected);
      if (!alreadyDetected.length > 0) {
        unmatchedPairs.push([user, users[i]]);
        unmatchedPairsFinal.push([user, users[i]]);
      }
    }
  });
}
console.log(unmatchedPairs);
console.log(unmatchedPairsFinal);
```